# Best @font-face syntax approach

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I've been using this model

```
@font-face {
font-weight: WEIGHT;
font-style: STYLE;
font-family: 'NAME';
src: url('font.eot');
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/dey3lzjdpgszxzt/myriad-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), 
 url('font.woff') format('woff'), 
 url('font.ttf') format('truetype'), 
 url('font') format('svg'); }
```

and

```
font: SIZE "NAME", FALLBACK, GENERIC FAMILY;
```

But I've been warned this is not the best approach as it differs from the "[Bulletproof syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)", which eventually became outdated because of a bug in IE <9 and was [updated three years ago by Fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax).

Is the latter one still perfect or now outdated too?

[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) stated recently that using

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

is enough, but without mentioning IE <9 compatibility.

What is the best practice and is there a *bulletproof* one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, read all over, and know, you need to consider the following :

Example:

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('WebFont.eot');
    src: url('WebFont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
         url('WebFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('WebFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('WebFont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}
```

Considerations:

1. always use relative (same domain) font URLs
2. include `src: url('WebFont.eot');` at first even if it is there in the second src
3. first definition in second `src` should be EOT definition, with iefix hashtag fix
4. include .eot, .woff, .ttf, and .svg **respectively** in your CSS definition.
5. Always expect that it will not work on <=iPhone 4s, <=Galaxy S III, and other elder ones.

You can always refer to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ , and download the webfont kit for any font there (respecting their licenses), see how CSS is included within.

An intensive tutorial would be here : [INSTALLING WEB FONTS, START TO FINISH!](http://zoerooney.com/blog/tutorials/installing-web-fonts-start-to-finish/)

Comment: Can anyone clarify why point 2 needs to be followed and what it achieves?

Comment: An SVG font is not necessary. The few browsers that supports SVG fonts are covered by either TTF or WOFF. SVG fonts are likely to go away in the future. (however, if not speaking about fonts, SVG is wonderful)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a comment I read on https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/:

> FYI: Issue: @font-face wasn't rendering in IE7 on windows vista but
> fine in IE7 on windows xp and windows 7. Solution: Use double quotes
> instead of single.
>
> Who are still using windows vista and IE7? OMG

So using double quotes makes it better.

Also adding more fonts makes it better, here's an example I used in one project and that works even in IE 5, IE 7-11, (old versions of IE have been tested in IE 11 emulator) Chrome, Firefox and Opera and some other old and modern desktop and mobile browsers:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Noto Sans";
  src: url("fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Regular.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url("fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Regular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url("fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url("fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Regular.woff") format("woff"), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url("fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Regular.ttf")  format("truetype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url("fonts/NotoSans/NotoSans-Regular.svg#NotoSans") format("svg"); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Comment: I've improved the post with an example.